# odata filering of complex types

Tags: c#, odata, iqueryable

I have complex object type in Xml it looks like:

```
<Event>
 <id>3198588</id>
 <title>SunSay</title>
  <artists>
    <artist>SunSay</artist>
    <headliner>SunSay</headliner>
  </artists>
</Event>
```

It's returning data in XML via ApiController using oData. So, I want to filter by artist name (SunSay), what I have to to place in $filter= ?
Url looks like: http://localhost:2048/api/Values/Madrid?filter=...
I don't have .svc in this project which can take a path.